# cd Terminal at a given directory after running a Python script?

Tags: python, bash, shell, directory, terminal

I'm working on a simple Python script that can use `subprocess` and/or `os` to execute some commands, which is working fine.

However, when the script exits I'd like to `cd` the actual Terminal (in this case OS X) so on exit, the new files are ready to use in the directory where the have been created. All the following (`subprocess.Popen`, `os.system`, `os.chdir`) can do what I want from *within* the script (i.e. they execute stuff in the target directory) but on exit leave the Terminal at the *script's own* directory, not the *target* directory.

I'd like to avoid writing a shell script to temporary file just to achieve this, if this is at all possible anyway?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sadly, no.  Processes are not allowed to change the environment of their parent process, and in this case your Python script is a child process of the shell.  You could "fake" it by having your Python process set up a new shell - call subprocess to open a shell process and present it to the user, inheriting the modified environment from itself - but that has the downside of forcing the Python process to run continually.

This is really what shell scripts are for.. :-)  Someone clearly needs to write a more traditional shell (e.g. closer to Bash than IPython) which can use python as its scripting language.

Comment: Thanks - I'll rewrite is as a shell script, and call the Python from there instead :-)

Comment: You don't need to leave the Python interpreter hanging around. You just need to get the process environment the way you want it (e.g. `os.chdir()`) and then `os.execv()` a new shell. Yes, you'll still have a subordinate shell running, but the Python interpreter will have been replaced. http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.execv

Comment: @msw: I've never been able to reliably pull that off on all platforms with shells in particular (specifically powershell), but I should have suggested that.

Answer (score 4):

Forgetting Python for the moment, no subprocess can change the state of its invoking shell. Thus you need a construct which alters the state of the calling shell which is what Paul Creasey was hinting at.

```
alias mycd="cd `echo $1`"
```

where `echo` could be replaced with `script_which_outputs_a_directory_name_on_stdout.py` It's kind of a hack, but at least it's an old hack.

Comment: I see what you mean; however (if I don't rewrite is as a shell script), I think I'll print 'cd [path_to_dir]' at the end so it can just be copied to the command line!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply running the program in the current shell?

i.e

`$. script.py`

instead of

`$script.py`

Comment: You can't run a **non-shell** script in the current shell. The dot prefix makes no difference in this case.